# Using If true then copy in a For Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am really new to using vba. What I want to do is to look into the cells of a column one by one for the value "1".

If found, then move 4 columns back and copy the contents to the upper row. And repeat this for the whole column. I tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```
Sub find()
'
' find Macro

    Range("M1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

       For Each xCell In Selection
       If ActiveCell.Value = 1 Then
       ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Copy
       ActiveCell.Offset(-1, -4).Select
       ActiveSheet.Paste
       'Else
       'ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      End If
      Next xCell


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You're working with ActiveCell while looping xCell. Generally you don't have to work with Selection and ActiveCell. Youre Sub should look something like that:

```
Sub find()

    For Each xcell In Range(Range("M1"), Range("M1").End(xlDown))
        If xcell.Value = 1 Then
           xcell.Offset(0, -4).Copy Destination:=xcell.Offset(-1, -4)
        End If
    Next xcell

End Sub
```